# Java - IOException: The system cannot find path specified

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String separator = File.separator;
        String filename = "myFile.txt";
        String directory = "mydir1" + separator + "mydir2";  

        File f = new File(directory,filename);
        if (f.exists()) {
            System.out.print("filename:" + f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("filesize:" + f.length());
        } else {
            f.getParentFile().getParentFile().mkdir();
            try{
                f.createNewFile();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is create file "myFile.txt" under the folder "mydir1", but the console says "the system cannot find the path specified", can someone tell me where did I do wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats a mighty convoluted way of creating a file in `mydir1`. Why even bother with `mydir2` ? Your stack trace will give you a lot of info **(that should be included in your question!)**. I suspect `f.getParentFile().getParentFile().mkdir();` is causing problems, but since you have 3 operations there it may not be clear which one is the issue. Instinct tells me "How can I get the parent of a non existent file?", but that could just be my suspicious nature and lack of recent Java IO work ;-)

Comment: does the parent directory exist?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you create only `mydir1` but not `mydir2`.

I can suggest instead of

```
f.getParentFile().getParentFile().mkdir();
```

try something like:

```
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

[File.mkdirs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs--) will try to create all required parrent directories.

Comment: so if I want to create a new file in the specified directory, then I have to find the exact same directory path as the directory path I put into File f = new File(directory,filename), otherwise I cannot manage to change the path by f.getParentFile().getParentFile().mkdir() right? sorry for my bad English, hope you understand what I am trying to say

Comment: You will not be able to create a file in unexisting directory. You should create directories structure first.

Comment: Okay now I get it. Thanks for your explanation.